# Can Canny edge detecor return the original image

Tags: java

Hi i have an image processing project using Canny edge detector, and was just wondering, is there any way to bring back the original image with the edges detected, instead of black and white, and if so how?

Comment: What if you superimposed the pictures and used a filter to remove the black(non-edges) from the edge detected image?